# Translucent sheets of polycarbonate or polyester. Safe to make a crinkle toy for my plastic packaging loving cat?

Tags: cats, behavior, safety, toys

My 1.5 year old calico is perfect in every way except she cannot resist the crinkly temptation of plastic bags and packaging. Since adopting, the family has been mindful of how one handles plastic wrappers and packaging stuffs, out of consideration for the critter. Being a cat, she sneaks about to hunt the material down, anyway. She is conscious the humans in her house have discouraged indulging this particular impulse. When we catch her, she looks up, and darts off. There must be something worth it about chewing plastic. Pity she can't explain the appeal.

I post to ask, if the material used to make theatre lighting filters/gels (translucent polyester or polycarbonate sheets, the ultimate crinkle stuff) can be used safely to make a crinkle toy, or perhaps stuff in another material for the sound?

Explanation of the gels could be found [in a relevant article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_gel) (source: Wikipedia).

Thank you much for any wisdom you can share.

Comment: it is better to use wrapping paper,the brown type is less toxic than the glossy type it is a bit less crinkly,the plastic type do often have a layer of metall on it and this is toxic so it is best to avoid it.

Comment: I would just buy crinkly cat toys such as crinkle balls which are pretty cheap, quite easy to find, and I would assume made out of materials safe for cats, unless the cat manages to rip off pieces. As with any pet toy, take the item away if it starts breaking in a way that's unsafe.

Comment: Even which kind of toy one produces: there should be no parts that the cat could swallow or inhalate. If it is the noise your cat likes most, you could cover some of the materials with a tightly woven fabric. I have done such for a toddler. Maybe you could find some instructions in this area. https://www.cucicucicoo.com/2014/02/how-to-make-crinkle-taggie-baby-toy/